# Prove that if $\lvert x-x_0\rvert<\min(\frac{\epsilon}{2\lvert y_0\lvert+1},1)$ and $\lvert y-y_0\rvert<\frac{\epsilon}{2\lvert x_0\lvert+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Prove that if $\lvert x-x_0\rvert<\min(\frac{\epsilon}{2\lvert y_0\lvert+1},1)$ and $\lvert y-y_0\rvert<\frac{\epsilon}{2\lvert x_0\lvert+1}$, then $\lvert xy-x_0y_0\rvert<\epsilon$

any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By triangle inequality, and since $xy-x_0y_0=(xy-x_0y)+(x_0y-x_0y_0)$ we have
\begin{align}
|xy-x_0y_0|&\le|xy-x_0y|+|x_0y-x_0y_0|&&\text{Triangle inequality}\\[3pt]
&=|x||y-y_0|+|x_0||y-y_0|&&\text{Absolute value properties}\\[4pt]
&=\left(|x|+|x_0|\right)|y-y_0|&&\\[4pt]
&\le\left(|x-x_0|+|x_0|+|x_0|\right)|y-y_0|&&\text{Triangle inequality}\\[4pt]
&<|y-y_0|+2|x_0||y-y_0|&&\text{Since }|x-x_0|<1\\[4pt]
&=\left(1+2|x_0|\right)|y-y_0|\\[4pt]
&<\left(1+2|x_0|\right)\frac{\varepsilon}{1+2|x_0|}&&\text{Cause }|y-y_0|<\frac{\varepsilon}{1+2|x_0|}\\[4pt]
&=\varepsilon
\end{align}